# inserting html into an xml query using CDATA

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to insert the content of an html file into a xml request .

I am opening the html file this way :

```
page =  open(html).read()
```

then inserting the content in the xml this way :

```
"<Description><![CDATA["+page+"]]</Description>"+\
```

This errors out this way :

> XML Parse error. 
> XML Error Text: "; nested exception is: 
>     org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and
>   end within the same entity."

I'm assuming I have to do a bit more than just dumping the content of the html file into a CDATA tag ? or maybe do it in a different way ?

Comment: You need to end your CDATA with `]]>` not `]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the closing `>` for the `CDATA` element:

```
"<Description><![CDATA["+page+"]]></Description>"+\
```

Answer (score 3):

Two potential issues.

First, the correct way to end a `CDATA` block is with `]]>`, not `]]`

Second, your HTML data might include CDATA blocks, and [nested CDATA blocks are not allowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Nesting).  You might consider *encoding* your HTML data, using Base64 for example:

```
import base64
encPage = base64.b64encode(page)
```